# No leader at end of round 1

Tags: two-rooms-and-a-boom

In the game Two Rooms and a Boom, the leader of a room is the first person to be nominated by another player.  What happens if no one has done this in a room by the end of round one and the room has no leader?

Comment: I would assume from the tone of the rooms that this should be just avoided by the players. Since all that needs to happen is for one person to nominate someone it ought to happen within 3 minutes.

Comment: @Guvante It is certainly very easy to nominate a leader, but with smaller number of highly suspicious players, it is possible for it to not happen.  The rules don't have a good answer as to what you do in that case.  I'm wondering if anyone has a solution to this.

Comment: I think it is just one of the things your group will need to decide upon. Maybe if a minute has gone by without a leader someone can speak up and ask for people to volunteer. Hopefully someone will want to stay or go and can nominate someone to perform that task in their stead.

Comment: If three minutes can pass with not even a joking nomination or somebody to step up to a not-a-big-deal responsibility, you may not have a group that will fully enjoy that game....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is there isn't a rule that covers this eventuality. The rules state however:

> In Two Rooms and a Boom, part of the fun is the lack of rules. Players can say
>   whatever they want, do whatever they want, and come up with whatever strategy they
>   want.

I think it would be a fairly easy to say a leader *must* be chosen before people swap between rooms. Otherwise you could ask the question what if someone hasn't been chosen by a leader before rooms must swap? The answer is the game doesn't work. You *have* to send someone across and so you also *have* to have a leader by that point.

If your group is struggling in particular with this then maybe you need to appoint a Games Master for the game for a few playthroughs until people get into the swing of it?

We play this game almost every week for multiple rounds at the University game society. We have never had this problem. (In fact it is rare that leader isn't decided within a few seconds of a round starting as nearly always the first question asked is "Who should be leader?")